# Latex Remove Spaces Between Items in List

Tags: latex

What is the best way to format a list as to remove the spaces between list items.

Comment: See also: [Reduce space between enumerated items on tex.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6081/5645)

Answer (score 206, accepted):

It's easier with the enumitem package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
Less space:
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
  \item foo
  \item bar
  \item baz
\end{itemize}

Even more compact:
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
  \item foo
  \item bar
  \item baz
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

The enumitem package provides a lot of features to customize bullets, numbering and lengths.

The paralist package provides very compact lists: compactitem, compactenum and even lists within paragraphs like inparaenum and inparaitem.

Comment: If you want to remove the spacing globally for every list in your document just put `\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep}` in your preamble.

Comment: This doesn't work in my machine, could be the package version?

Comment: @RSFalcon7 : You need to specify the ``enumitem`` package beforehand: ``\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep}`` ... also setting the itemsep for the whole document to a certain value works that way ``\setlist[itemize]{itemsep=1cm}``

Comment: @marvin_dpr Thanks, the problem is a bit old, but I think that my installation of texlive wasn't the best. After the reinstallation everything returned as it was supposed to be.

Comment: How do you get rid of the bullets?

Comment: I would also like to add that the `nolistsep` option is [now deprecated](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf), and that its successor is `nosep`, which "kills all vertical spacing".

Answer (score 50):

You could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Normal:

\begin{itemize}
  \item foo
  \item bar
  \item baz
\end{itemize}

Less space:

\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
  \item foo
  \item bar
  \item baz
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

This question was already asked on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/vertical-space-in-lists. The highest voted answer also mentioned the `enumitem` package (here answered by Stefan), but I also like this one, which involves creating your own itemizing environment instead of loading a new package:

```
\newenvironment{myitemize}
{ \begin{itemize}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}     }
{ \end{itemize}                  }
```

Which should be used like this:

```
\begin{myitemize} 
  \item one 
  \item two 
  \item three 
\end{myitemize}
```

Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136050/12065

Answer (score 2):

`compactitem` does the job.

```
\usepackage{paralist}

...

\begin{compactitem}[$\bullet$]
    \item Element 1
    \item Element 2
\end{compactitem}
\vspace{\baselineskip} % new line after list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this with negative numbers to change the separation manually

```
\begin{itemize}
\itemsep-1.5em
  \item foo
  \item bar
  \item baz
\end{itemize}
```